# Any space can be a Euclidean space?

Tags: linear-algebra

Is it true that any vectorial space $(V,+,\cdot, K)$, over a general field $K$ can be organized as a Euclidean space? I am trying to define rotation in general vector spaces, and I need to define a scalar product on any linear space.

Comment: Isn't it part of the definition of euclidean space that the field is $\mathbb{R}$? If you disagree, you'll need to say exactly what you mean by "euclidean space".

Comment: What is your definition of a Euclidean space? And what properties do you want the scalar property to have?

Comment: All I wanted to say is how can we define a scalar product on a general vector space, over a general vector field?

Comment: @Bogdan Do you want things like *positive definiteness* from the scalar product?

Comment: In my opinion this cannot be done with fields of positive characteristic. What should "positiveness" be?

Comment: We need to find a total order over $K$...

Comment: Ordered fields have all characteristic 0.

Comment: Isn't it true that for every abstact set one can induce a total order?

Comment: @Bogdan in a finite field, there is no total order satisfying $\forall x: x < x+1$.

Answer (score 1):

You can get something like a Euclidean space with a scalar product using any *ordered* field. However, most presentations of Euclidean geometry require "completeness" axioms that force the ordered field to be Archimedean and as large as possible: the only candidate is then $\Bbb R$.

In a vector space over any field, you can mimic the ordinary scalar product: however, it doesn't always have the nice properties usually required of a real inner product.